# Update specific nugets to desired version using Cake

Tags: c#, cakebuild

I have a cake build which I am using to update Nugets like this

```
Task("Update-NuGet-Packages")
.Does(() =>
{
    NuGetUpdate(@"D:\FooBar\FooBar.sln");
});
```

This does update nuget to latest version in all solution projects but is there an option to pass package name and version, much like we do through package console

```
Update-Package NLog -Version 3.5.0
```

Comment: Are you not pinning to a specific version in either the packages.config file or in the csproj file, depending on what project format you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in a `NuGetUpdateSettings` into the second argument, this has a list of `Id`s to update:

```
Task("Update-NuGet-Packages")
.Does(() =>
{
    NuGetUpdate(@"D:\FooBar\FooBar.sln",
                new NuGetUpdateSettings(){
                       Id = new [] { "Newtonsoft.Json", "HumbleConfig" }
                     });
});
```

However, looking at `NuGetUpdater` there doesn't seem to be a way to pass in the version numbers. Doesn't look that hard to extend and I'm sure they'd be happy to accept a PR.

NuGetUpdateSettings - https://github.com/cake-build/cake/blob/main/src/Cake.Common/Tools/NuGet/Update/NuGetUpdateSettings.cs

NuGetUpdater - https://github.com/cake-build/cake/blob/main/src/Cake.Common/Tools/NuGet/Update/NuGetUpdater.cs

Comment: This is what I was thinking. +1 from me.

Comment: for me it is not working. The references are maintained in the csproj-file. I only get following message: "No projects found with packages.config."